# Blowfish encryption with custom salt in Java

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish

In PHP, the implementation of Blowfish hashing is just calling the function 
`string crypt(string $str [,string $salt])` and passing an appropriate string salt consisting of a "$2a$", "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters (http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) :

```
<?php
  echo crypt('SAD123', sprintf('$2a$10$%s', '7711cbpe58dfpogiu04985'));
```

The result is:

```
$2a$10$7711cbpe58dfpogiu0498u5Vh773A3qx.3LE3ro3NX7F9c9N7.pOm
```

Now I need to move this implementation to Java (or Scala), and have no ideas how to get the **same result**...

p.s. I'm using `Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try the [jBcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) library:

```
public String crypt(String clearText) {
    return BCrypt.hashpw(clearText, BCrypt.gensalt(10));
}
```

Please note that I used 10 as cost factor just to adhere to your example code, but 12 or greater would be better.

For completeness, this is how to reproduce your example:

```
String encrypted = BCrypt.hashpw("SAD123", "$2a$10$7711cbpe58dfpogiu04985");
// encrypted is $2a$10$7711cbpe58dfpogiu0498u5Vh773A3qx.3LE3ro3NX7F9c9N7.pOm
```

Comment: Thank you, that works fine :-)
I believe there MUST be a standard Java api way though )))

Comment: PHP's `crypt()` function implements bcrypt under the hood (when called with the appropriated salt), [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php). Bcrypt is based on Blowfish (which is a symmetric block cipher), but uses a particular key schedule phase which makes it a one-way hashing algorithm. While Java provides an implementation of Blowfish, I don't think you can build a bcrypt implementation on top of it due to these differencies (jBcrypt itself is a pure java implementation and doesn't rely on the standard api).